# Can anyone help on this "svn merge" problem?

Tags: svn, merge, svn-reintegrate

I had this error when doing a command like this from a supercomputer:

```
svn merge --reintegrate https://vlab.noaa.gov/svn/lamp-oper/lamp/branches/lmp.v2.5.0
```

The error is this:

```
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
svn: E175002: REPORT request on '/svn/lamp-oper/!svn/me' failed
```

I was trying to merge my branch (which has a URL https://vlab.noaa.gov/svn/lamp-oper/lamp/branches/lmp.v2.5.0 ) with the trunk, which has a URL as https://vlab.noaa.gov/svn/lamp-oper/lamp/trunk

We have a huge "fix" area on the branch and I guess it timed out or something like that? I knew when I was checking out the trunk, I had this error. I just checked out the files under fix first, then the two subdirectories ("eqns" and "meld_eqns") separately. But I don't know if I could do similar things with "svn merge".  The problem occurred when it was deleting numerous equations in that "eqns" subdirectory.

I tried `svn merge --reintegrate https://vlab.noaa.gov/svn/lamp-oper/lamp/branches/lmp.v2.5.0/fix --depth files` but it said `--reintegrate` cannot be used with `--depth`. Is there an option to merge the files first and then the sub-directories later, just like `svn checkout`?

Comment: Are you using an up to date version of SVN client and server?

Comment: version 1.14.0 is what I used.

Comment: I'd advise always merging whole branches and from the root of the branch. Because 1) each revision should be one complete state of the repository (not something half-merged) and 2) small mistakes can create spurious mergeinfo which you will have to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the error log of your HTTP server. I think there might be an issue with file or directory permissions inside the repository. Make sure all files and directories are (at least) readable for the user running Apache.

Comment: I don't think I had a permission issue here.  I have the full permission to edit the repository and the file permissions were right.